# How to make Devise's authenticate_user method return js.erb views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have a Rails 3.2 app that shows a Devise login page via jquery-ujs. In application.html.erb I have:

```
<%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :remote => true %>
```

which calls /views/devise/sessions/**new.js.erb**, containing some JS that displays a nice modal login form on the existing page.
That all works fine, but in my controller I have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

which redirects users calling new / edit / update / destroy actions to /views/devise/sessions/**new.html.erb**.
This happens even when the action in question is called with :remote => true from the view.

How would I change :authenticate_user! to return new.js.erb instead of redirecting to the .html.erb version?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I could make this just writting the *.js.erb template after generating the devise:views, but in devise version 2.1.2  I couldn't make it in further versions.

Comment: Yes you would have thougbht it'd be that easy, but it doesn't seem to be with the current version!

Comment: Actually in the v3 I'veen able to use *.js templates to respond actions.